# C++ WinHttp get response header and body

Tags: c++, winapi, httprequest, httpresponse, winhttp

I'm currently trying to write a class to make sending simple requests easier for me.
In the end I'd like it to be usable somewhat like this:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    HttpRequest Request(L"Example UserAgent/1.0",L"",L"");
    Request.SendRequest(L"google.com",L"GET",NULL);
    if (Request.responseHeader)
        printf("%s",Request.responseHeader);
    if (Request.responseBody)
        printf("%s",Request.responseBody);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

But for now it doesn't work at all. I have no idea how I could get the response header and I'm failing writing the response header to a public member of my class.
Yeah I'm really bad at C++ especially when it's about the winapi.
Well I hope you can help me out.
Here is my code so far:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <winhttp.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "winhttp.lib")

class HttpRequest {
  private:
    DWORD dwSize;
    DWORD dwDownloaded;
    LPSTR pszOutBuffer;
    BOOL  bResults;
    HINTERNET hSession;
    HINTERNET hConnect;
    HINTERNET hRequest;
    LPCWSTR _userAgent;
    //LPCWSTR _proxyIp;
    //LPCWSTR _proxyPort;
    size_t bodySize;
  public:
    HttpRequest(LPCWSTR, LPCWSTR, LPCWSTR);
    void SendRequest(LPCWSTR, LPCWSTR, LPVOID);
    LPSTR responseHeader[1000000];
    LPSTR responseBody[1000000];
};

HttpRequest::HttpRequest(LPCWSTR userAgent, LPCWSTR proxyIp, LPCWSTR proxyPort) {
    _userAgent = userAgent;
    //_proxyIp = proxyIp;
    //_proxyPort = proxyPort;
    hSession = WinHttpOpen( userAgent, WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_DEFAULT_PROXY, WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_NAME, WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_BYPASS, 0 );
}

void HttpRequest::SendRequest(LPCWSTR url, LPCWSTR method, LPVOID body) {
    bodySize = 0;
    if (hSession)
        hConnect = WinHttpConnect( hSession, url, INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTPS_PORT, 0 );
    else
        printf("session handle failed\n");
    if (hConnect)
        hRequest = WinHttpOpenRequest( hConnect, method, NULL, NULL, WINHTTP_NO_REFERER, WINHTTP_DEFAULT_ACCEPT_TYPES, WINHTTP_FLAG_SECURE );
    else
        printf("connect handle failed\n");
    if (hRequest)
        bResults = WinHttpSendRequest( hRequest, WINHTTP_NO_ADDITIONAL_HEADERS, 0, body, 0, 0, 0 );
    else
        printf("request handle failed\n");

    if( bResults )
        bResults = WinHttpReceiveResponse( hRequest, NULL );
    if( bResults )
    {
        do 
        {
            // Check for available data.
            dwSize = 0;
            if( !WinHttpQueryDataAvailable( hRequest, &dwSize ) )
                printf( "Error %u in WinHttpQueryDataAvailable.\n", GetLastError( ) );

            // Allocate space for the buffer.
            pszOutBuffer = new char[dwSize+1];
            if( !pszOutBuffer )
            {
                printf( "Out of memory\n" );
                dwSize=0;
            }
            else
            {
                // Read the data.
                ZeroMemory( pszOutBuffer, dwSize+1 );

                if( !WinHttpReadData( hRequest, (LPVOID)pszOutBuffer, dwSize, &dwDownloaded ) )
                    printf( "Error %u in WinHttpReadData.\n", GetLastError( ) );
                else { 
                    //printf( "%s", pszOutBuffer );
                    responseBody[bodySize++] = pszOutBuffer; 
                }
                // Free the memory allocated to the buffer.
                delete [] pszOutBuffer;
            }
        } while( dwSize > 0 );
    }

    // Report any errors.
    if( !bResults )
        printf( "Error %d has occurred.\n", GetLastError( ) );

    // Close any open handles.
    if( hRequest ) WinHttpCloseHandle( hRequest );
    if( hConnect ) WinHttpCloseHandle( hConnect );
    if( hSession ) WinHttpCloseHandle( hSession );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`WinHttpQueryHeaders()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384102%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to access the response headers. Use the `WINHTTP_QUERY_RAW_HEADERS(_CRLF)` flag to specify that you want to retrieve all of the available headers.

You also need to change your class to dynamically allocate its `responseHeader` and `responseBody` members. You are wasting a lot of memory, as well as limiting the response size you can handle, by using static arrays.

Try this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <winhttp.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#pragma comment(lib, "winhttp.lib")

class HttpRequest
{
private:
    std::wstring _userAgent;
    //std::wstring _proxyIp;
    //std::wstring _proxyPort;
public:
    HttpRequest(const std::wstring&, const std::wstring&, const std::wstring&);
    bool SendRequest(const std::wstring&, const std::wstring&, void*, DWORD);
    std::wstring responseHeader;
    std::vector<BYTE> responseBody;
};

HttpRequest::HttpRequest(const std::wstring &userAgent, const std::wstring &proxyIp, const std::wstring &proxyPort) :
    _userAgent(userAgent)
    //,_proxyIp(proxyIp)
    //,_proxyPort(proxyPort)
{
}

bool HttpRequest::SendRequest(const std::wstring &url, const std::wstring &method, void *body, DWORD bodySize)
{
    DWORD dwSize;
    DWORD dwDownloaded;
    DWORD headerSize = 0;
    BOOL  bResults = FALSE;
    HINTERNET hSession;
    HINTERNET hConnect;
    HINTERNET hRequest;

    responseHeader.resize(0);
    responseBody.resize(0);

    hSession = WinHttpOpen( _userAgent.c_str(), WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_DEFAULT_PROXY, WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_NAME, WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_BYPASS, 0 );
    if (hSession)
        hConnect = WinHttpConnect( hSession, url.c_str(), INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTPS_PORT, 0 );
    else
        printf("session handle failed\n");

    if (hConnect)
        hRequest = WinHttpOpenRequest( hConnect, method.c_str(), NULL, NULL, WINHTTP_NO_REFERER, WINHTTP_DEFAULT_ACCEPT_TYPES, WINHTTP_FLAG_SECURE );
    else
        printf("connect handle failed\n");

    if (hRequest)
        bResults = WinHttpSendRequest( hRequest, WINHTTP_NO_ADDITIONAL_HEADERS, 0, body, bodySize, 0, 0 );
    else
        printf("request handle failed\n");

    if (bResults)
        bResults = WinHttpReceiveResponse( hRequest, NULL );
    if (bResults)
    {
        bResults = WinHttpQueryHeaders(hRequest, WINHTTP_QUERY_RAW_HEADERS_CRLF, NULL, WINHTTP_NO_OUTPUT_BUFFER, &headerSize, WINHTTP_NO_HEADER_INDEX);
        if ((!bResults) && (GetLastError() == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER))
        {
            responseHeader.resize(headerSize / sizeof(wchar_t));
            if (responseHeader.empty())
            {
                bResults = TRUE;
            }
            else
            {
                bResults = WinHttpQueryHeaders(hRequest, WINHTTP_QUERY_RAW_HEADERS_CRLF, NULL, &responseHeader[0], &headerSize, WINHTTP_NO_HEADER_INDEX);
                if( !bResults ) headerSize = 0;
                responseHeader.resize(headerSize / sizeof(wchar_t));
            }
        }
    }
    if (bResults)
    {
        do
        {
            // Check for available data.
            dwSize = 0;
            bResults = WinHttpQueryDataAvailable( hRequest, &dwSize );
            if (!bResults)
            {
                printf( "Error %u in WinHttpQueryDataAvailable.\n", GetLastError( ) );
                break;
            }

            if (dwSize == 0)
                break;

            do
            {
                // Allocate space for the buffer.
                DWORD dwOffset = responseBody.size();
                responseBody.resize(dwOffset+dwSize);

                // Read the data.
                bResults = WinHttpReadData( hRequest, &responseBody[dwOffset], dwSize, &dwDownloaded );
                if (!bResults)
                {
                    printf( "Error %u in WinHttpReadData.\n", GetLastError( ) );
                    dwDownloaded = 0;
                }

                responseBody.resize(dwOffset+dwDownloaded);

                if (dwDownloaded == 0)
                    break;

                dwSize -= dwDownloaded;
            }
            while (dwSize > 0);
        }
        while (true);
    }

    // Report any errors.
    if (!bResults)
        printf( "Error %d has occurred.\n", GetLastError( ) );

    // Close any open handles.
    if( hRequest ) WinHttpCloseHandle( hRequest );
    if( hConnect ) WinHttpCloseHandle( hConnect );
    if( hSession ) WinHttpCloseHandle( hSession );

    return bResults;
}
```

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    HttpRequest Request(L"Example UserAgent/1.0",L"",L"");
    if (Request.SendRequest(L"google.com",L"GET",NULL,0))
    {
        printf("%ls",Request.responseHeader.c_str());
        if (!Request.responseBody.empty())
            printf("%*s",Request.responseBody.size(),(char*)&Request.responseBody[0]);
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. There seems to be something wrong with the vectors though. I've never used vectors and I'm not sure if I understand them. I get the following error: Debug Assertion Failed! | File: c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\vector | Line: 932 | Expression: vector subscript out of range  ... I'm also wondering how I would get the byte size of the request body and if it would be possible to calculate it in the function. Here is the modified version: http://pastebin.com/ye8JUm4A the request and the response are sent correctly, the app just fails with the vectors...

Comment: Works fine when I try it, no out of range errors.  However, I have tweaked the code for you, just in case. When `SendRequest()` returns true, you can retreive the body size via `responseBody.size()`. It is not always possible to get the body size ahead of time, for instance when HTTP's `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` header is used. So you just keep reading until the end of the response is reached.

Comment: I don't get it, why would only I get this error. How is that possible? What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: That is what a debugger is for.

Comment: Well, I've never used vectors before. I have absolutely no idea how they work. [...] if (size() <= _Pos) { // report error [...] I guess that means that responseBody.resize(dwOffset+dwSize); didn't make the vector large enough for the data that was being read into it. But from what I can tell it looks right. Maybe I just need to change a setting in my vc++? I mean since the code per se works for you, it should be correct.

Comment: A vector is just a dynamic array, like a wrapper around `new[]` and `delete[]`. If you are going to code in C++ then you should get familiar with C++'s clases. If you are more comfortable with `new`/`delete` then switch, but you are likely still going to have problems if you are not doing the right things. There is no `_Pos` in the code I gave you, so what exactly are you validating? I tested the code that I gave you.

Comment: The debugger pointed me to the code with the _Pos. It's part of the vector lib. I had to change lots of things in the code you gave me in the first place btw. There were some issues with the arguments of the constructor, with {, } and :, with responseHeader being called responseHeaders sometimes. I also don't think that this line is valid: _userAgent(userAgent) ... I just changed it to _userAgent = userAgent; ... Well I corrected these and added some other small things like accepting proxies and a request header. The added features work just fine. It just only when it gets to the vectors.

Comment: The code I gave you compiles and runs just fine in my compiler. Yes, my original code had some typos, but I fixed those. Did you not try the new code yet? And yes, `_userAgent(userAgent)` is valid code, it is in the constructor's **initialization list** (see the `:` before the list?).

Comment: You edited the code? Well, that explains a lot. I'll check it out later.